# Is it possible to set a javascript number to 32 bits?

Tags: javascript, numbers

Is it possible to set a javascript number to 32 bits instead of 64?

Comment: No, but you can just use only 32 of 64 bits? Please tell us what you want to do where you needed that.

Comment: If you got many values and are concerned about memory space you could take a look about typed arrays (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Float32Array), but as Bergi said javacript only support 64 bit floats, using typed arrays the 64bit value is rounded to 32 to storage and promoted to 64 when read.

Comment: I'm building a graphing calculator and want to use 32 bit to improve speed.

Comment: JavaScript numbers aren’t 64-bit integers. They’re doubles.

Comment: `N % (2 ** 32)` would be an option to get the lower half. `Math.floor(N / (2 ** 32))` is one to get the upper half. ;-; I had to convert a `Date.now()` since i was using an ECS library that only supported 32-bit integers.

Answer (score 4):

According to JS Definitive Guide if you do bitwise operations, the number converts automatically to 32 bits:

> The bitwise operators expect integer operands and behave as if those
>   values were represented as 32-bit integers rather than 64-bit
>   floating-point values. These operators convert their operands to
>   numbers, if necessary, and then coerce the numeric values to 32-bit
>   integers by dropping any fractional part and any bits beyond the 32nd.
>   The shift operators require a right-side operand between 0 and 31.
>   After converting this operand to an unsigned 32-bit integer, they drop
>   any bits beyond the 5th, which yields a number in the appropriate
>   range.

All you have to do is perform a bitwise operation on the number, such as ORing it with 0. You will have the same number but it will be 32 bits.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this question when looking to take javascript numbers and "convert" them to 32 bits, because the Web Audio API stores AudioParam values as 32 bits, and I was having issues comparing my values from my application's state with the AudioParam value, and them not being the same.

I eventually learned about `Math.fround()`, which will round your number to:

> the nearest 32-bit single precision float representation of a Number

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/fround

So, depending on your use case, this might work for you.